# AJAX - reload page if JSON has changed

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I cannot find a suitable way to achieve this:

I have this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateSpots() {

    $.ajax({
        url : '/epark/api/spots/last',
        dataType : 'text',
        success : function(data) {

            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            var currentMessage = json.dateTime;
            var idPosto = json.idPosto;
            console.log('current '+currentMessage);
            console.log('old '+oldMessage);
            if(currentMessage != oldMessage){

                setTimeout(function(){location.reload();}, 5000);

                $('#idPosto').toggle("higlight");
            }
            oldMessage = currentMessage;    

        }
    });

}

var intervalId = 0;
intervalId = setInterval(updateSpots, 3000);
var oldMessage ="";

</script>
```

This should check every 3 seconds if the `dateTime`has changed on the JSON.

The problem is that I cannot get to go further first step. I mean, when the page loads, `oldMessage`empty so the if condition is not satisfied. If I could "jump" this first iteration, then everything would go well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var oldMessage = false;

//...

if (oldMessage && oldMessage !== currentMessage) {

//...
```

Comment: You could leave the initializer as an empty string, but I think `false` is clearer